# rdiff-backup bash script and cron trouble

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have this very simple bash script:

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
/opt/bin/rdiff-backup --force --print-statistics myhost::/var/bkp /volume1/backups/sql 2>&1 > /var/log/rdiff-backup.log;
/opt/bin/rdiff-backup --force --print-statistics myhost::/var/www/vhosts /volume1/backups/vhosts 2>&1 >> /var/log/rdiff-backup.log;
/opt/bin/rdiff-backup --force --print-statistics myhost::/etc /volume1/backups/etc 2>&1 >> /var/log/rdiff-backup.log;
/opt/bin/rdiff-backup --force --print-statistics /volume1/homes /volume1/backups/homes 2>&1 >> /var/log/rdiff-backup.log;
cat /var/log/rdiff-backup.log | /opt/bin/nail -s "rdiff-backup log" me@email.com;
```

if I run the script from the command line, in this way:

```
nohup /path/to/my/scipt.sh &
```

it works fine, appending each rdiff-backup statistic report to the rdiff-backup.log and sending this file to my email address, as expected. But if I put the script in the crontab, the script make only one rdiff-backup job sending statistics via email. I cannot understand because the script doesn't work in the same way...

Any idea?

this is my cronjob entry:

```
30 19 * * * /opt/bin/bash /volume1/backups/backup.sh
```

via crontab only the last job is executed correctly, I think because this is the only one local backup. When I execute the script from command line I use the root user, and the public key of the root user is in the /root/./ssh/authorized_keys of the remote machine. The owner of the crontab file is the root user too, I created them through "crontab -e" using the root account.

Comment: can you be more specific on ", the script make only one rdiff-backup job sending statistics via email" which one is executed correctly. Can you also show your cronjob entry ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure the script used in cron doesn't output anything, otherwise:

1. cron will assume there is an error
2. you will not see the error if any

A solution for this is to use

```
30 19 * * * /opt/bin/bash /volume1/backups/backup.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/rdiff-backup-cron.log;
```

Second of all, it appears you are losing env variables when executing via cron, try adding the env settings to your script

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
. /root/.profile
/opt/bin/rdiff-backup --force --print-statistics myhost::/var/bkp /volume1/backups/sql 2>&1 > /var/log/rdiff-backup.log
```

if `/root/.profile` doesn't, exist try adding `. /root/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`

I hope this helps.